# What are the strenghts and weaknesses of Whirlpool Hashing Algorithm

Tags: encryption, hash

I want to find out if the Whirlpool hashing algorithm have any weaknesses. There are quite a bit of articles explaining the strengths of this algorithm, but for some reason I cannot find any on its weaknesses...perhaps there aren't any?

Answer (score 2):

This far there are no known significant cryptographic weaknesses in Whirlpool hash algorithm.

The biggest practical concern would appear to be:

- Whirlpool performance is lower than many other hash functions (see e.g., http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html)

Because of this speed issue, something like SHA-512 often gets more use.